# Animated SVG file not animating

Tags: android, svg, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I have an animated .SVG that animates perfectly in the browser, but when I import it into Andoroid Studio via the [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg), it turns it into a flat, monochrome image that doesn't animate. How do I keep Android Studio from breaking the file?

Here is the .xml file it converts it to:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100"
    android:viewportHeight="100">
  <path
      android:pathData="M50,21.5L50,21.5A3,2.15 0,0 1,53 23.65L53,36.35A3,2.15 0,0 1,50 38.5L50,38.5A3,2.15 0,0 1,47 36.35L47,23.65A3,2.15 0,0 1,50 21.5z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M66.752,26.943L66.752,26.943A2.15,3 126,0 1,67.915 30.446L60.45,40.72A2.15,3 126,0 1,56.76 40.696L56.76,40.696A2.15,3 126,0 1,55.596 37.194L63.061,26.919A2.15,3 126,0 1,66.752 26.943z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M77.105,41.193L77.105,41.193A3,2.15 72,0 1,75.987 44.711L63.909,48.635A3,2.15 72,0 1,60.937 46.446L60.937,46.446A3,2.15 72,0 1,62.055 42.929L74.133,39.004A3,2.15 72,0 1,77.105 41.193z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M77.105,58.807L77.105,58.807A3,2.15 108,0 1,74.133 60.996L62.055,57.071A3,2.15 108,0 1,60.937 53.554L60.937,53.554A3,2.15 108,0 1,63.909 51.365L75.987,55.289A3,2.15 108,0 1,77.105 58.807z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M66.752,73.057L66.752,73.057A2.15,3 54,0 1,63.061 73.081L55.596,62.806A2.15,3 54,0 1,56.76 59.304L56.76,59.304A2.15,3 54,0 1,60.45 59.28L67.915,69.554A2.15,3 54,0 1,66.752 73.057z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M50,78.5L50,78.5A2.15,3 90,0 1,47 76.35L47,63.65A2.15,3 90,0 1,50 61.5L50,61.5A2.15,3 90,0 1,53 63.65L53,76.35A2.15,3 90,0 1,50 78.5z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M33.248,73.057L33.248,73.057A2.15,3 126,0 1,32.085 69.554L39.55,59.28A2.15,3 126,0 1,43.24 59.304L43.24,59.304A2.15,3 126,0 1,44.404 62.806L36.939,73.081A2.15,3 126,0 1,33.248 73.057z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M22.895,58.807L22.895,58.807A3,2.15 72,0 1,24.013 55.289L36.091,51.365A3,2.15 72,0 1,39.063 53.554L39.063,53.554A3,2.15 72,0 1,37.945 57.071L25.867,60.996A3,2.15 72,0 1,22.895 58.807z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M22.895,41.193L22.895,41.193A3,2.15 108,0 1,25.867 39.004L37.945,42.929A3,2.15 108,0 1,39.063 46.446L39.063,46.446A3,2.15 108,0 1,36.091 48.635L24.013,44.711A3,2.15 108,0 1,22.895 41.193z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M33.248,26.943L33.248,26.943A2.15,3 54,0 1,36.939 26.919L44.404,37.194A2.15,3 54,0 1,43.24 40.696L43.24,40.696A2.15,3 54,0 1,39.55 40.72L32.085,30.446A2.15,3 54,0 1,33.248 26.943z"
      android:fillColor="#91979b"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: You can only convert simple SVGs to VectorDrawable format.  The format does not support SVG animations.  Android also has an AnimatedVectorDrawable class. But the type of animations it supports are also very limited. As as far as I know there is no way to automatically convert SVGs to that format.  You have to do it yourself manually.  There are some other libraries that allow some SVG animation.  But we can't recommend any without seeing your SVG and what sort of animation it does.

Comment: SVG is here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pWRO6j9u4mmpKYFkN6wlsKlyxwqUCkU6/view?usp=sharing. 

Animation is so foreign to me so I was looking for premade solutions, but I may have to learn myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd use [AnimatedSvgView](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView), you'd only have to add these paths into a `string-array`.

Comment: Does that work for any other animation besides the one pictured? Can't find any reference to other animations in the repo.